# Как вывести всех людей из ответа json в 1 сообщение? [Discord.PY]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Всем привет, собственно пишу бота discord. Я только начинающий, и я не могу понять, как вывести всех людей из ответа json в 1 сообщение.

Есть такой код

```
for user in r["response"]["profiles"]:
    print(f"{user["first_name"]} {user["last_name"]} {"| Бан" if "deactivated" in user else " "}")
```

Ответ response: если нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так вот, нужно вывести всех людей в формате `await ctx.send("Имя Фамилия | Бан \n")` и по новой. только в 1 сообщении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вывести всё в одном сообщении через конкатенацию строк, таким образов, при итерации каждая строка будет записываться с новой строки.

```
message = ""
for user in r["response"]["profiles"]:
    message += (f"\n{user["first_name"]} {user["last_name"]} {"| Бан" if "deactivated" in user else " "}")
await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]